# How to view a SVG-symbol-file with GeoTools, before choosing it for the map layer?

Tags: geotools

I'm creating a list of all SVG symbols I have in a library. When I define a Style for a e.g point layer I'm selecting a SVG file from this list.
I would like to display the symbol in a e.g Frame when I click on the symbol, to see if it is the right one before I create the style for the layer. Apache batik can't handle SVGs with parameters "fill="param(fill)", just hard coded.

I wounder, since GeoTools can handle this together with Style, is there a simple way in GeoTools just to draw a SVG symbol in e.g a Frame?

If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit complicated to do, but it can be done. The best example is in GeoServer's [`org.geoserver.wms.legendgraphic.BufferedImageLegendGraphicBuilder`](https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/blob/f588dbbf13a3b8538cadcb911579b12b0f03747d/src/wms/src/main/java/org/geoserver/wms/legendgraphic/BufferedImageLegendGraphicBuilder.java). This first [creates a sample feature](https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/blob/98d05ae6245fa88ec8072b0741402e3b1900aad4/src/wms/src/main/java/org/geoserver/wms/legendgraphic/LegendGraphicBuilder.java#L448) and then calls [`StyledShapePainter`](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/06d379a2fdbfdbf94641c16813c37ef02aa7f63c/modules/library/render/src/main/java/org/geotools/renderer/lite/StyledShapePainter.java) (in GeoTools) to draw that feature onto a `Graphics2D` that you can then display.

Comment: I don't know how to set up the BufferedImageLegendGraphicBuilder, all I have is a SVG, size and colors. It should be set up with a "GetLegendGraphicRequest". This I don't know how to get/create...

Comment: I'm not sure you need to follow that chain exactly but the code should show you how to solve your problem

Comment: I think I got it. It works, but not to 100 %. I added my solution with a coment on what doesn't work. Any one?

Answer (score 0):

First I create a temporary Style from all the inputs and an empty BufferedImage, then I send it SymViewer who draws a feature in a JPanel.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import org.geotools.map.legend.Drawer;
import org.geotools.styling.Style;
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.LineString;
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.Point;
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.Polygon;
import org.opengis.feature.simple.SimpleFeature;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import java.awt.SystemColor;

public class SymViewer extends JFrame {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   private JPanel contentPane;
   /**
   * Create the frame.
   */
   public SymViewer(BufferedImage img, Style style, String title, String titleExtra, String geoType) {
       setBackground(SystemColor.text);
       setTitle(title + " " + titleExtra);
       BufferedImage image = drawSymbolic(img, style, geoType);
       setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       setBounds(0, 0, 439, 266);
       contentPane = new JPanel();
       contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
       setContentPane(contentPane);
       contentPane.setLayout(null);
       JPanel panel = new JPanel() {
          private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
          @Override
          protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
             super.paintComponent(g);
             g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
          }
       };
       panel.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0)));
       panel.setBounds(0, 0, 434, 261);
       panel.setBackground(SystemColor.menu);
       contentPane.add(panel);
    }


  private BufferedImage drawSymbolic(BufferedImage img, Style style, String geoType) {
      Drawer drawer =  Drawer.create();
      SimpleFeature feature = null;
          if (geoType.contains("Line")){
            LineString line = drawer.line(new int[] { 15, 15, 400, 20, 15, 200 });
            feature = drawer.feature(line);
          } 
          else if(geoType.contains("Polygon")) {
            Polygon  p = drawer.polygon(new int[] { 15, 15, 400, 5, 400, 200, 15, 200, 15, 15  });
            feature = drawer.feature(p);
          } 
          else if(geoType.contains("Point")) {
            Point p = drawer.point(216, 130);
            feature = drawer.feature(p);
          } 
          if(feature != null) {
              drawer.drawDirect(img, feature, style);
              return img;
          }
          return null;
      }
  }
```

There is one problem: If I create e.g. a polygon style which I want to fill with a PNG image. It will not be filled in my SymViewer (just a grey filled area). Im my map it will be correctly filled with the PNG image. I create the style in exactly the same way from a SLD-file. What could be wrong?
SLD file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<sld:StyledLayerDescriptor  
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" 
    xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld"
    xmlns:sld="http://www.opengis.net/sld" 
    xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    version="1.0.0">
  <sld:NamedLayer>
    <sld:Name>Graphic fill</sld:Name>
    <sld:UserStyle>
      <sld:Title>Graphic fill</sld:Title>
      <sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
        <sld:Rule>
          <sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <sld:Fill>
              <sld:GraphicFill>
                <sld:Graphic>
                  <sld:ExternalGraphic>
                    <sld:OnlineResource
                      xlink:type="simple"
                      xlink:href="magnus.png" />
                    <sld:Format>image/png</sld:Format>
                  </sld:ExternalGraphic>
                <sld:Size>93</sld:Size>
                </sld:Graphic>
              </sld:GraphicFill>
            </sld:Fill>
          </sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </sld:Rule>
      </sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
    </sld:UserStyle>
  </sld:NamedLayer>
</sld:StyledLayerDescriptor>
```